# Check duplicate ActiveRecord and return duplicate column name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Suppose I have a model `User` with `columns: name, mobile, email, card_num, etc.`

The mobile, email, card_num cannot duplicate.

```
validates_uniqueness_of :mobile
validates_uniqueness_of :email
validates_uniqueness_of :card_num
```

Is there anyway to have any checking, at most in **ONE** query for any duplicate records and return the duplicate column?

Existing record:

```
name   mobile     email            card_num
============================================
Mary   65666678   mary@gmail.com   A001
```

New record 1:

```
name   mobile     email            card_num
============================================
Peter  65666678   peter@gmail.com  A002
```

Will return "**mobile**"

New record 2:

```
name   mobile     email            card_num
============================================
Peter  74009822   mary@gmail.com   A002
```

Will return "**email**"

New record 3:

```
name   mobile     email            card_num
============================================
Peter  65666678   mary@gmail.com   A001
```

Return either "**email**" / "**mobile**" / "**card_num**" is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you can try this way:

Consider you are inserting new record -2 then you just fire query as:

```
User.select("CASE 
       WHEN (name = 'Peter') THEN 'name'
       WHEN (mobile = '74009822') THEN 'mobile'
       WHEN (email = 'mary@gmail.com') THEN 'email'
       ELSE 'card_num'
      END as col_name").where("name = 'Peter' or mobile = '74009822' or email = 'mary@gmail.com' or card_num='A002'")
```